# Finding key in a list of dictionaries and sorting the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Having a JSON-like structure:

```
{
    "shopping_list": [
        {
            "level": 0,
            "position": 0,
            "item_name": "Gold Badge"

        },
        {
            "level": 1,
            "position": 10,
            "item_name": "Silver Badge"

        },
        {
            "level": 2,
            "position": 20,
            "item_name": "Bronze Badge"

        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to sort the list by key.

However, when trying to get them by:

```py
k = [c.keys()[0] for c in complete_list["shopping_list"]]
```

I get `TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing`.

1. How to get keys?
2. How to sort the list by specified key?

Comment: What do you mean by _sort the list by key_?

Comment: If you want a list of the keys, it's... `list(c.keys())` (or just `list(c)`). But which key do you want to sort by? Try e.g. `sorted(complete_list["shopping_list"], key=lambda c: c["item_name"])`.

Comment: `sorted(complete_list["shopping_list"], key=lambda x: x['level'])`

Comment: @MrGeek: it seems I wasn't clear enough: I'd like to have the entries (dictionaries) sorted by value of specified key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is (admitting the key you mention is 'level'):

```
k = sorted([c for c in complete_list["shopping_list"]], key=lambda x: x['level'])

print(k) 
# >> [{'level': 0, 'position': 0, 'item_name': 'Gold Badge'}, {'level': 1, 'position': 10, 'item_name': 'Silver Badge'}, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the keys in a list of lists :

```
d = {
    "shopping_list": [
    ...
}
k = [list(c.keys()) for c in d["shopping_list"]]
print(k)
```

**Output** :

```
[['item_name', 'level', 'position'], ['item_name', 'level', 'position'], ['item_name', 'level', 'position']]
```

However even if you wanted to sort this list of lists based on some specific key value say value for `"level"` key or `"position"` key, the list of lists would remain same.